# Error while using jersey-client - No generator was provided

Tags: jersey, glassfish-3, jersey-client

This is the error code which I am getting, Looks like some conflicting jar is throwing the error but not sure what is the reason or which conflict version is giving the error. Attaching the dependency tree along with.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:285)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:245)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:90)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:38)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:55)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:73)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.InjectionManagerFactory.create(InjectionManagerFactory.java:32)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:44)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:413)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:820)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getClientRuntime(ClientRequest.java:176)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getInjectionManager(ClientRequest.java:567)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.onBuilder(JerseyWebTarget.java:371)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:199)
    at shaded.xyz.org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:38)
    at com.xyz.ec.ac.rest.RestClient.getBuilder(RestClient.scala:60)
```

This is the code which is giving the error at this point RestClient.getBuilder(RestClient.scala:60)

```
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import javax.ws.rs.client.{Client, ClientBuilder, Entity, Invocation}
import javax.ws.rs.core.{Feature, MediaType, Response}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

abstract class RestClient(conf: RestConf) {

  // some ac services require this property
  val METHOD_OVERRIDE = "X-HTTP-Method-Override"
  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  val client: Client = createClient

  def postWithRetries(url: String, body: String): Response = {
    retry(conf.retries)(post(url, body))
  }

  def post(url: String,
           body: String,
           headers: Map[String, String]): Response = {

    val builder = getBuilder(url, headers)
    val entity = Entity.entity(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    builder.post(entity, classOf[Response])
  }

  def post(url: String,
           body: String): Response = {
    post(url, body, Map.empty)
  }

  def getWithRetries(url: String, headers: Map[String, String]): Response = {
    retry(conf.retries)(get(url, headers))
  }

  def get(url: String): Response = {
    get(url, Map.empty)
  }

  def get(url: String,
          headers: Map[String, String]): Response = {

    val builder = getBuilder(url, headers)
    builder.get(classOf[Response])
  }

  private def getBuilder(url: String, headers: Map[String, String]): Invocation.Builder = {

    val feature = getFeature

    if (feature.isDefined){
      client.register(feature.get, -1)
    }

    val builder = client
      .target(url)
      .request()
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
      .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)

    headers.foreach(x => builder.header(x._1, x._2))

    builder
  }

  def close(): Unit ={
    client.close()
  }

  @annotation.tailrec
  private def retry[T](n: Int)(f: => T): T = {
    Try(f) match {
      case Success(x) => x
      case _ if n > 1 =>
        val m = n - 1
        logger.warn(s"failed to make request. attempting request number ${conf.retries - m}")
        retry(m)(f)
      case Failure(e) =>
        logger.error(s"failed to make request after ${conf.retries} attempts", e)
        throw e
    }
  }

  private def createClient: Client = {
    ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
      .readTimeout(conf.readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .connectTimeout(conf.connectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .build()
  }

  def getFeature: Option[Feature]
}
```

The above code is giving issue.Below is dependency tree

```
    [INFO] +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
    [INFO] +- net.codingwell:scala-guice_2.11:jar:4.2.11:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.4:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-CR2:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.25.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.41:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.41:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.security:oauth1-client:jar:2.36:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.security:oauth1-signature:jar:2.36:compile
    [INFO] +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.0:compile
    [INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.4.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.2.0-b21:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.7.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.7.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
```

Comment: Are you running on GlassFish as suggested by one of the tags you picked? You should then remove **all** runtime JEE dependencies form pom.xml or mark them provided for the simple reason because GlassFish *already* provides them out the box!